# how can i delay the server request if its being sent repeatedly in Reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a checkbox input for a to-do-list app and, when I mark the task as done a request, will be sent to the server to update it
but I think it can slow down the server as you can check and uncheck the input repeatedly
so is there any way to delay the requests? for example, 300ms after the checkbox is changed
here is my code

```
const [todos, setTodos] = React.useState([]);

const completedOnChangeHandler = (e, id) => {
    const x = e.target.checked;
    console.log(x);

    axios
      .patch(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/todo/todos/${id}/`, {
        completed: x,
      })
      .then(
        (response) => {
          console.log(response.data);

          setTodos([response.data]);
        },
        (error) => {
          console.log(error);
        }
      );
  };

return (
    <form>
          {todos.map((todo) => (
            <ul key={todo.id}>
              <li>{todo.title}</li>
              <li>{todo.description}</li>
              <button>delete</button>
              <input
                type="checkbox"
                placeholder="completed"
                onChange={(e) => completedOnChangeHandler(e, todo.id)}
                checked={todo.completed}
              />
            </ul>
          ))}
    </form>
  );
};

export default Form;
```

Comment: Create a submit button that only does a patch request when its clicked?

Comment: debouncing can help you here

Comment: [From the horse's mouth](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html#how-can-i-prevent-a-function-from-being-called-too-quickly-or-too-many-times-in-a-row).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should debounce the request and disable the checkbox while the request is in progress to avoid a race condition.
Here is an example of a debounce function:

```
function debounce(func, timeout = 300){
  let timer;
  return (...args) => {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(() => { func.apply(this, args); }, timeout);
  };
}
function saveInput(){
  console.log('Saving data');
}
const processChange = debounce(() => saveInput());
```

Or you can use lodash/debounce, if the lodash package is available in your project.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the debouce function from lodash or if you don't want to add the whole lib to your project, you could use: [lodash.debouce](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash.debounce)

You can set the amount of time you want between requests and it will manage it for you.

Answer (score 0):

You could perhaps declare a variable/state that contains the time of the last time your input was checked.

Everytime the user check the input you compare the current time with the last time your input was checked. If the delta is superior than 300ms you send your http request.

You can use the module `Date` with the method `Date.now()`.
This method returns the number of milliseconds elapsed since January 1, 1970 00:00:00 UTC.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a React [Native] example. In order to read/write variables without triggering a render, we can utilize useRef to track the timerId that we need to clear on each input. Personally, anything more than 250ms might seem slow so that is why I'm using 200ms to acccount for the time it takes to make a network request.

```
import { useState, useRef } from 'react';
import { Searchbar } from 'react-native-paper';

export default function DelayedExample() {
    const [searchQuery, setSearchQuery] = useState('');
    const searchTimer = useRef(null);

    function onChangeSearch(query) {
        setSearchQuery(query);
        clearTimeout(searchTimer.current);
        // delay searching for better UX and lower processing
        searchTimer.current = setTimeout(() => {
            // make web requests and show search results
        }, 200);
    }

    return (
        <Searchbar
            placeholder="Search"
            onChangeText={onChangeSearch}
            value={searchQuery}
        />
    );
}
```